# Binary Input Validator in Angular (TypeScript)

Tags: angular, typescript

Using typescript, i am trying to ensure that an input field only takes binary (0 and 1).

My html

```
<div>
     <input type="text" (keypress) = "binaryValidate($event)">
</div>
```

My ts

```
binaryValidate(evt: number) {
    if (evt === 1 ) {
        return true;
    } else if (evt === 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

for some reason it only returns false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event is not not a number, but `KeyboardEvent`. What you're looking for is testing its `key`:

```
binaryValidate(evt: KeyboardEvent) {
  const value = evt.key;
  return value === "1" || value === "0";
}
```

Try on [codesabdbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-smoke-8lrmz?file=/src/app/app.component.ts:236-249)